# Sorting an async relationship

Tags: asynchronous, ember.js, promise

I have an ember app which shows **'competitions'**, each **'competition'** object has many **'competitor'** objects:

**app/models/competition.js**

```
import DS from "ember-data";

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  competitors: DS.hasMany('competitor', {async: true}),
});
```

I have a league-table component which is passed a **'competition'** object as its main data.

**app/components/league-table.js**

```
import Ember from "ember";

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  classNames: ['league-table'],
  competition: null,
  visibleCompetitors: Ember.computed.filterBy('competition.competitors', 'hidden', false),
  sortProperties: ['score:desc'],
  sortedCompetitors: Ember.computed.sort('visibleCompetitors', 'sortProperties'),
});
```

I would like to present the **competitors** in the correct order as a simple list. The sort order is determined by a complicated '**score**' property of the **competitor** which is calculated based on a significant amount of data which is embedded in the **competitor** object when it is loaded.

**app/templates/components/league-table.hbs**

```
<header>
  <h2>{{competition.name}}</h2>
</header>
<ul>
  {{#each sortedCompetitors as |competitor index|}}
      {{competitor-item competitor=competitor}}
  {{else}}
    <li class="centered">competition has no competitors</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

The server takes a long time to load the '**competition.competitors**' list so I was hoping to have the league table populate gradually and have **competitors** slot into the correct positions as they are loaded.

My problem is that **competitor** objects are not correctly ordered. I can see this is something to do with the promise but I can't realistically wait for all the **competitors** to load before rendering something.

Is there a way to restructure this so the **competitors** are slotted into the correct positions as they are loaded or do I need to think about the problem in a different way?

Comment: Did you consider to fetch related `competitors` in your routes model hook?

Comment: All of the competitors come back in one shot though correct?

Comment: Conceptually if you have a lot of data and the load time is big I would suggest you to use back-end pagination. Depending on what is your back-end, what type of Adapter you use and how you integrate it with Ember the way you would fetch the following data-chunk, then trigger the recalculation and display the recalculated result would vary.